# Jquery 1.2.6 .click on body doesn't have any effect

Tags: jquery

I have a script that completly work with JQuery 1.5.2 but it doesn't with 1.2.6, only the **$('body').click** doesn't have any effect.

I have made an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Awea/MkYMF/), someone have an idea to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `.closest()`, which wasn't added to jQuery until 1.3. See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for more info.

If you really need to maintain support for the very old jq1.2.6, you might be able to shim in  [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) instead.

Comment: Thanks ! I replace it by .parents()

Comment: @Awea Haha yeah, I just added that :)

Comment: I try it with 1.6.4 and I have the same problem, you know why ?

Comment: @Awea that looks like a [bug in jsfiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689070/is-jquery-1-6-4-broken-or-did-something-change). If you change the fiddle to load the script during the `onDomReady` event, it works ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mharen/MkYMF/3/))