# Is jQuery 1.6.4 broken or did something change?

Tags: jquery

It works in jQuery 1.6.3 but not jQuery 1.6.4

http://jsfiddle.net/xxwr4/

```
$("#a").click(function(){
    alert("click");              
});

<a id='a' href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: I noticed this too this morning in js fiddle..

Comment: ha! I noticed it *last night*!  Can't figure out if it's jQuery or jsfiddle but I think it's more likely that it's jsfiddle

Comment: they have fixed it https://twitter.com/#!/js_fiddle/status/122346841932169216

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is jsFiddle's bad I believe, not jQuery.

I get an error when trying to attach to the `window`'s load event. Something tells me they've pushed an un-tested update.

> [11:01:16.970] window.addEvent is not a function @ http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:18

So, what's basically happening is your event isn't being attached because when it tries to bind your javascript code to execute after the DOM is ready it bombs. Switching to [no wrap (body)](http://jsfiddle.net/xxwr4/1/) in the fiddle allows it to work.

Comment: but it works when you select an older version of jQuery

Comment: @Homer: The difference is that of using `window.addEvent('load',function(){ ...yourcode... });` (1.6.4) vs. `$(window).load(function(){ ...yourcode... });` (1.6.3)

Comment: They have fixed it. https://twitter.com/#!/js_fiddle/status/122346841932169216

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it's jsFiddle that's broken. If you switch it to "onDomReady" it works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on jsfiddle's side. If you change it from onLoad to onDomReady it'll correct the problem.